# MySql query consist of query and values in one variable to execute in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am looking for how to write a query which contains query with values as one single parameter execute(sql) unlike query and values passed as separate parameters to execute(query, values).

Below are the details I am looking into.

###Required Solution###

```
value1 = 'ABC'
value2 = 'XYZ'
query = f'SELECT column1, column2 from table1 where column1 = {value1} or column2 = {value1}'

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
```

**Result of above**

query output = 'SELECT column1, column2 from table1 where column1 = ABC or column2 = XYZ'

Error :: Query syntax is invalid

Findings :: I am thinking as value1 and value2 are not getting assigned as string values the issue is causing.

###Working Solution###

```
sql = "SELECT column1, column2 from table1 where column1 = {value1} or column2 = {value1}"
val = ("ABC", "XYZ")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```

But I am looking in particular to the details provided in the required solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your required solution is susceptible to SQL injection.
Always recommend to use parameterized queries instead of directly interpolating or concatenating values into the SQL string.

However, if you absolutely need to use that approach, ensure that your string values are enclosed in quotes to be treated as strings in the SQL query:

```
value1 = "'ABC'"
value2 = "'XYZ'"
query = f'SELECT column1, column2 from table1 where column1 = {value1} or column2 = {value2}'

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(query)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Prefect solution! Answer is working as expected. Thank you 'Yuri R'!
I agree that concatenating values is not an approachable way to write query. Having an requirement to fulfill this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **[Yuri R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025602/yuri-r)**; `f-string` generally is prone to SQL injection attacks. Another way of achieving your result is to use `%s` param in case you're looking for it.

```
value1 = 'ABC'
value2 = 'XYZ'
query = 'SELECT column1, column2 from table1 where column1 = %s or column2 = %s'

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(query, (value1, value2))
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: my requirement is to just send only one parameter that is query and no value parameters while doing execute(query). If the execute(query, values) then above works as mentioned. But, Thanks for looking into the details.